# Direct limit of $CW$ complex and infinite Stiefel manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, fiber-bundles, stiefel-manifolds

Let $V_{n}(\mathbb{R}^k)$ be the Stiefel manifold of ortogonal $n$-frames in $\mathbb{R}^k$ and $G$ a compact Lie group. A classifyng space for group $G$ is a connected topological space $BG$, together a principal $G$-bundle $EG \rightarrow BG$ such that the following is true. For any compact T2 space $X$ there is a one-to-one corrispondence between the equivalence classes of principal $G$-bundles on $X$ and the homotopy classes of maps from $X$ to $BG$. So why this definition implies that if we have a principal $G$-bundle $E \rightarrow B$ with the property that the total space $E$ is conctratible, then $(B,E)$ is a classifyng space for $G$?
If we consider the $GL(n)$-principal bundle $V_{n}(\mathbb{R}^k) \rightarrow Gr_{n}(\mathbb{R}^k)$ we have to consider the direct limit on $k$ of $V_{n}(\mathbb{R}^k)$ obtaining 
$$ \underrightarrow{\lim}_kV_n(\mathbb{R}^k)=V_n(\mathbb{R}^\infty) $$
but what is really the direct limit? How can I imagine it and write it formally?

Comment: When you want to write «$G$-bundle» type it as `$G$-bundle`, not `$G-$bundle`, for the latter has both wrong spacing and a wrong dash!

Comment: The direct limit is the usual direct limit of topological spaces: is that what you are asking?. This should be explained in Wikipedia, but probably it would be best to look in some good textbook.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I'm sorry, I edited. What is the usual direct limit of topological spaces? How can I build it?

Answer (score 0):

A direct limit in topological spaces has as underlying set the corresponding direct limit of sets, and its topology is the "weak topology" or "final topology" for which a subset is open precisely if its restriction to all the stages (in the sequence that the direct limit is over) is open.

Generally, the direct limit is a special case of a colimit of topological spaces, and colimits of topological spaces are computed as the underlying colimits of sets equipped with the maximum collection of open subsets that have the property that their preimage in all the spaces in the diagram that the colimit is over is open.

See here for more https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Top#UniversalConstructions